# How to disable clipboard function on TightVNC server

Tags: ubuntu, vnc, ubuntu-18.04, vncserver, tightvnc

I looked at the manual of TightVNC Server but I couldn't find any option to disable clipboard function in order to block copy/paste between host machine and remote machine.

I use TightVNC Server (version 1.3.10) on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a missing feature. Maybe requesting feature add from https://www.tightvnc.com/rfe.php

This seems like a similar request that was created in 2005 and not resolved.